# Tachyonic field

Tags: cosmology, symmetry-breaking, tachyon

i'm working on a  paper about symmetron cosmology. symmetron is a scalar field that by its symmetry breaking can explain the  dark energy.

the action is:
[image]

ans A , V are assumed to be:

[image]
[image]

where M and [image] are mass scales and lambda in a coupling.

somewhere in this paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.2112) "we get interested in the case where the field becomes tachyonic around current cosmic density,

[image]

my questions are:

> 1. what is the meaning of a field becomes tachyonic?
> 2. where the above approximation come from?

thank you so mach

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133490/2451

Comment: Tachyonic is essentially synonymous with locally unstable. The potential at $\phi=0$ becomes a local maximum, so the na\:ive mass squared for the field becomes negative. It's indicating that the vacuum configuration is changing to some nonzero $\phi$.

Comment: ok, now I understand the meaning of tachyonic, thanks to you. it means where p=M2m2 . Could you please explain how p=h0^2 Mpl^2?
do you mean that current cosmic density is where /phi/=0?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the meaning of a field becomes tachyonic?

It means that it has a negative coefficient at the $\phi^2$ term in action. The propagator of such field oscillates on the space-like region and decreases exponentially on the time-like region, so it's particles (tachyons) travel faster than the speed of light. It doesn't contradict SR since the commutator $\left[ \phi(x); \phi(y) \right]$ vanishes at space-like intervals, so causality is preserved. However, tachyonic fields have no stable vacuum state.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your helps!

I figure out that what is the meaning of the field becomes tachyonic.

when

[image]

it is where the phase transition occurs and the symmetry breaks.
we take the current density proportional to critical density and so we have the above approximation.

thak you Holographer and Hindsight.